# How can i resolve the dependency using .NET 4's Lazy<T> type in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am developing an application using .net core API, where my all dependent services resolved by .net core DI. but few are the API's are also dependent on a third-party VoIP server(some class libraries). I want to develop a singleton class for only the VoIP server's classes, that's why I don't want use .net core DI or not to involve them with the .net core DI. And that singleton class will access .net core Interface and services. How can I resolve the dependency using .NET 4's Lazy type.

DI Resolved By:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMumbleServerClient, MumbleServerClient>();
```

**Code Sample:**

```
public sealed class MumbleScheduler
{
    private readonly IMumbleServerClient _mumbleServerClient;
    private Timer tm = null;

    private static readonly Lazy<MumbleScheduler>
            lazy =
            new Lazy<MumbleScheduler>
                (() => new MumbleScheduler());

    public static MumbleScheduler Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private MumbleScheduler()
    {
        _mumbleServerClient = ?; //How can i set the reference here ? 
    }
}
```

Comment: The concept of DI itself has nothing to do with your framework. If `MumbleScheduler` needs an `IMumbleServerClient`, pass it in the constructor. How `MumbleScheduler` is then constructed is up to the client (who may or may not use a framework to handle it).

Comment: Well, I feel silly for not seeing the problem now: your client can't call the constructor of course since it's `private`, because you insist on exposing the singleton-ness of the class in the class itself. My best advice there is to not do this: singletons are evil, whether or not they're offered up by dependency injection. If only a single `MumbleScheduler` makes sense, the client is perfectly capable of initializing and passing that single instance around as necessary, and in fact this is exactly what you want to ensure dependencies are not hidden.

Comment: If you *must* have a singleton managed by the class itself (and again, avoiding this tends to lead to code that's better to maintain in the long run) you can initialize it with a separate static `Initialize` method to play the part of the constructor in terms of setting properties (it can include a check to ensure it's not called twice). This likely obviates the need for `Lazy` as well, since that's a more predictable moment to construct than when the instance is first requested.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for your time and the answer, now I am using static Initializer to have the static setting properties.